# How to provide password in pdsh command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to run parallel command on multiple server using pdsh. Source to target server do not have passwordless authentication. How can I authenticate using password in pdsh?

```
pdsh -w admin@10.160.xx.xx uptime -v
10.160.xx.xx: Permission denied, please try again.
10.160.xx.xx: Permission denied, please try again.
10.160.xx.xx: admin@10.160.xx.xx: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
pdsh@Amans-MacBook-Pro: 10.160.xx.xx: ssh exited with exit code 25
```

I was expecting a prompt for password or anyway where I can pass the password in command it self as I will be passing multiple server in **"-w"** option?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Use ssh.  pdsh is "old" technology, and insecure, no corporate infrastructure would allow it, better learn the current standard IMHO.  And you can setup ssh keys so you do not have to handle passwords either (or use sshpass).

Comment: ssh keys based authentication is not allowed in this infra. That's why I need a light weight tool where I can use password. I am exploring ansible, will answer once I achive it.